# Как округлить время или дату до интервала?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как можно округлить время или дату до интервала из массива?

Допустим сейчас время `22.09.2020 09:31:56`

то результат должен быть таким (округлять в меньшую сторону)

```
60 -> 9:31 // час:минуты = если передать interval[0]
300 -> 9:30 // час:минуты = если передать interval[1]
900 -> 9:30 // час:минуты = если передать interval[2]
1800 -> 9:30 // час:минуты = если передать interval[3]
3600 -> 9:00 // час:минуты = если передать interval[4]
14400 -> 9:00 // час:минуты = если передать interval[5]
21600 -> 9:00 // час:минуты = если передать interval[6]
43200 -> 9:00 // час:минуты = если передать interval[7]
86400 -> 22.09 // день.месяц = если передать interval[8]
```

```js
let interval = [
  60,    // '1m'
  300,   // '5m'
  900,   // '15m'
  1800,  // '30m'
  3600,  // '1h'
  14400, // '4h'
  21600, // '6h'
  43200, // '12h'
  86400  // '1d'
];
let now = new Date().getTime(); // 1600755549267

function getDateTime(now, interval){
  return new Date(now);
}

// сам результат должен быть при вызове функции getDateTime
console.log(getDateTime(now, interval[2])); // к примеру на выводе должно быть "9:30"
```

Comment: Округлять к меньшему?

Comment: @UModeL, да, не знаю как только такое записать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делите на интервал (не забываем про миллисекунды, у вас секунды) округляем и умножаем обратно.
Считаем по формуле

```
CountOfPartsMilliseconds = Round(TimeMilliseconds/PartInMilliseconds)

TimeMilliseconds = CountOfPartsMilliseconds * PartInMilliseconds
```

```js
let interval = [
  60,    // '1m'
  300,   // '5m'
  900,   // '15m'
  1800,  // '30m'
  3600,  // '1h'
  14400, // '4h'
  21600, // '6h'
  43200, // '12h'
  86400  // '1d'
];
let now = new Date().getTime(); // 1600755549267

function getDateTime(now, interval){
  return new Date(Math.floor(new Date(now).getTime()/(interval*1000)) *(interval*1000));
}

// сам результат должен быть при вызове функции getDateTime
console.log(getDateTime(now, interval[2])); // к примеру на выводе должно быть "9:30"

console.log(new Date(1600755549267))
console.log(`округленное до минуты: ${getDateTime(new Date(1600755549267), interval[0])}`) 
console.log(`округленное до 5 мин минут: ${getDateTime(new Date(1600755549267), interval[1])}`)
console.log(`округленное до 15 мин минут: ${getDateTime(new Date(1600755549267), interval[2])}`)
console.log(`округленное до 30 мин минут: ${getDateTime(new Date(1600755549267), interval[3])}`)
console.log(`округленное до 1 час: ${getDateTime(new Date(1600755549267), interval[4])}`)
console.log(`округленное до 4 часов: ${getDateTime(new Date(1600755549267), interval[5])}`)
console.log(`округленное до 6 часов: ${getDateTime(new Date(1600755549267), interval[6])}`)
console.log(`округленное до 12 часов: ${getDateTime(new Date(1600755549267), interval[7])}`)
console.log(`округленное до 24 часов: ${getDateTime(new Date(1600755549267), interval[8])}`)
```

Если нужен определенный формат вывода то смотрите [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString())
```

Comment: Если передать что нужно то получите что хотели

Comment: @Aziz Umarov, это просто пример 1600755549267, наверное я его еще раньше записал, у stackoverflow какое то другое время не московское на выводе

Comment: Я добавил примеров для сравнения и работы плюс формулу для расчета

Comment: спасибо, вроде все правильно, попробую интегрировать в свой код. А как на выводе сделать такой результат `час:минуты` или `день.месяц` в виде строки?

Comment: Есть такие примеры, незнаю как правильно только их вставить в функцию `String(now.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');`, 
`String(now.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');`, 
`String(now.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');`, 
`String(now.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');`

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: У меня выводится `9/22/2020, 10:30:36 AM`

Comment: Посмотрите по ссылке как форматировать вывод